# Load file automatically on start up windows xp

Tags: boot, windows-xp

I have a few text files that I want to see every time I turn on the computer, like Post-It notes. So basically as the title says, how can I configure Windows XP to load specific files on startup?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a batch file which can run on startup. Se lets assume you have two files you want to open. Create a new text file on your Desktop and name it somefile.bat (Call it whatever you want so long as the extension is .bat).

Open the file in your text editor of choice and do something like:

`CD C:\path\to\file\1

start filename.txt

CD C:\path\to\file\2

start filename2.txt

exit;`

This opens the path then opens the file. The final line will close the command Window.

Now since I am not currently sat at a Windows XP machine you will have to read a couple things to get it started automatically.

It would seem this would be the best method for you:

```
1.Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2.Once the shortcut has been created right-click the file and select Cut.
3.Click Start, Programs, right-click the Startup folder and click Open
4.Once the Startup folder has been opened click Edit and paste the shortcut into the startup. Any shortcuts in the startup folder will automatically start each time Windows starts.
```

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm)

If this turns out to be incorrect you really shouldn't have to much difficulty finding how to make your file start with a simple Google search.

UPDATE: I run a similar .bat file to start a host of applications in work. I don't automate it on startup, but I know the file works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use registry too, (this solution can be used for most type of files not only txt files):

- Type `Regedit` in Run dialog
- Regedit (Registry Editor) will open (i think you know these steps how to open Regedit, but its just to make answer complete)
- Go to this key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- Every string value that you create here will be assumed as a file address and will be launched at Windows startup

Now you can do what you want in two ways:

1. Enter the file address directly as a string value:
   `C:\myPath\myText.txt` (will be open the file depended on what
   program is default program for these file types and associated to file
   extension)
2. Enter address of any desired program to open the file and
   then enter the file address as a parameter for entered program
   (using a space): `"C:\Program Files\myApp.exe"
   "C:\myPath\myText.txt"`